# Python variables and function not defined

Tags: python, global

in order to fix the NameError (name not defined problem) I used the global keyword like this, but I don't think it's a good solution. And I want to put the last part of the code into a function (main()), but then again the not defined error occurs with purchase_item function, Can someone help me improve this code?

```
from RetailItem import RetailItem
```

class CashRegister:

```
global Item_List
global Cashier_List
global total

Item_List = [ RetailItem("Item 1","Jacket", 12, 59.95),
              RetailItem("Item 2", "Designer Jeans", 40, 34.95),
              RetailItem("Item 3", "Shirt", 20, 24.95) ]
Cashier_List = []
total = 0

def purchase_item(RetailItem):
    global Cashier_List
    Cashier_List.append(RetailItem)

def get_total():
    global Cashier_List
    global total
    for o in Cashier_List:
        total += o.getPrice()
    return total

def show_items():
    global Cashier_List
    for o in Cashier_List:
        print(o)
def clear():
    global Cashier_List
    del Cashier_List[:]


print("Here are available items:")
for o in Item_List:
    print(o)
while True:
    x = input("Select items by number to buy or enter \"n\" to finish shopping: ")
    if x != "n":
        try:
            purchase_item(Item_List[int(x)-1])
            print("ADDED!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid number, try again!")
        except IndexError:
            print("Invalid number, try again!")
    else:
        break
print("......The total price is ${:0.2f}\n......This is your checkout items:".format(get_total()))
show_items()
```

Comment: Your code isn't showing properly. Can you format it so the indentation is properly visible?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand what your looking for. But I think you want declare the variables at the top with `Cashier_List`, with a default value. then use the functions to update the value.

Comment: You do not use `global` in the scope where you are declaring the variable.

Comment: Typically one would use `global` in a function to identify a variable outside the scope of that function which he would want to be able to write to. By default, all variables (global and local) are readable, but only local variables are writeable. So, if  you try to assign to a variable, it assumes it is local. That's why trying to assign to a global variable fails by default: Python is looking for a local, writeable variable by that name and doesn't find one. The `global` statement tells Python that you want to be able to assign to an external variable that would otherwise be 'missing'.

Comment: Since you already know that you principally should not use global, but rather do a rewrite. I'm hoping that you tried to solve a problem you had with your code by using global. What was that problem?